# Creating a Script to import users from a CSV to AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to build a script that will take a CSV with the fields

```
firstname, lastname, password
```

and create a user in AD in a specific OU with that info. I've done a bunch of googling, and this is what I've come up with (from [this blog](http://www.dannyeckes.com/powershell-bulk-user-import-in-server-2012/)):

```
Import-Csv .\userImport.csv | ForEach-Object {
  New-ADUser 
    -Name $_.DisplayName 
    -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName 
    -SamAccountName $_.Username 
    -FirstName $_.FirstName 
    -DisplayName $_.DisplayName 
    -LastName $_.Lastname 
    -Path $_.Path 
    -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.Password -AsPlainText -force) 
    -Enabled $True 
    -PasswordNeverExpires $True 
    -PassThru 
}
```

I have a few questions:

1. I want to specify the OU in my command, instead of having it be in the CSV. Can I just change it to:

   ```
   -Path OU=MyOU,DC=Domain,DC=Local
   ```
2. What is the `-PassThru` line for?
3. Is the `-AccountPassword` line correct? I got that from a blog that suggested this is the right way to take a password and set it as my AD user's password.
4. Do I need the `PrincipalName`, `SamAccountName` and `DisplayName` all as separate fields? This can be as minimal as possible, at least for now.
5. Any tips or changes you would make? This is my first time doing a script like this so I'm willing to learn.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can specify parameters whichever way you like, they don't need to come from the input file.
2. `-PassThru` makes `New-ADUser` echo the created user object. By default the cmdlet doesn't return anything.
3. Yes, the `-AccountPassword` argument is correct, provided the `password` field from the CSV contains the plaintext password.
4. You don't necessarily have to have a separate CSV field for each parameter argument if you can construct an argument from existing field values. For instance, you most likely can create values like `DisplayName` or `SamAccountName` from first and last name, e.g. like this:

   ```
   -SamAccountName ($_.firstname.Substring(0,1) + $_.lastname).ToLower()
   -DisplayName ('{0} {1}' -f $_.firstname, $_.lastname)
   ```

   You also don't need to specify every argument. For instance, the UPN (User Principal Name) will automatically be generated when omitted, and the display name will default to the name.
5. You can't wrap the lines like you have. PowerShell can't read your mind and won't know that you intend to continue the statement in the next line unless you tell it that or the statement is obviously incomplete. Use backticks to escape the linebreaks. Also, the parameters for first and last name are `-GivenName` and `-Surname`, not `-FirstName` and `-LastName`.

```bsh
$csv = '.\userImport.csv'
$ou  = 'OU=MyOU,DC=Domain,DC=Local'

Import-Csv $csv | ForEach-Object {
  $name = '{0} {1}' -f $_.firstname, $_.lastname
  $acct = ($_.firstname.Substring(0,1) + $_.lastname).ToLower()
  $pw   = ConvertTo-SecureString $_.password -AsPlainText -Force

  New-ADUser -Name $name `
    -SamAccountName $acct `
    -GivenName $_.firstname `
    -Surname $_.lastname `
    -Path $ou `
    -AccountPassword $pw `
    -Enabled $true `
    -PasswordNeverExpires $true `
    -PassThru
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. OU - If you want them all in the same OU, you can hard code it (remember the quotes)

   `-Path "OU=MyOU,DC=Domain,DC=Local"`
2. `-PassThru`

   > The `-PassThru` parameter lets you request output from cmdlets that return no output by default. ([The PassThru Parameter: Gimme Output](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2014/10/06/the-passthru-parameter-gimme-output/))

   i.e. Instead of `New-ADUser` just executing and then returning you to the next line, it will actually print out the new user created info to the prompt.
3. Yes the `-AccountPassword` takes a SecureString as the argument. The command `ConvertTo-SecureString` converts a plain text string to a SecureString, which then can be passed to the `-AccountPassword` parameter
4. You don't need `-UserPrincipalName`. You do need `-SamAccountName`. `-DisplayName` can be changed to:

   ```
   -DisplayName "$($_.FirstName) $($_.Lastname)"
   ```
5. This is a pretty standard script for mass producing accounts, so it is pretty good the way it is. The only change I would look at is `-PasswordNeverExpires $True` You typically only really set the Password Never Expires on Service accounts, so if you are creating plain old user accounts, you wouldn't need it.